# Spring Data: JPA Schema JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser intiailization fails

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to setup a project on spring data, but running into strange errors like this:

**problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser**

I have specified the proper schema namespace as guided in spring data JPA documententation site.

```
   
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"

jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.originations.dal.entities.dao"
```

I am not able figure out what i can do here.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [com/company/originations/apm/configservice/cra/test/OrderPersistenceTests-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser.(JpaRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler.init(JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler.java:34)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:130)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 69 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the Spring Data JPA dependency. If you are using maven you can include it by adding the following to your pom.xml `<dependencies>` tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven you can download the JAR here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.1.2.RELEASE

and add it to your project using whichever dependency management method you are using

Also make sure you have included the Spring AOP dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the JAR here - 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/3.1.2.RELEASE

Comment: I have both spring-data-common-core and spring-data-jpa dependencies in my project. But I am using 1.1.0 is that could be the reason?

Comment: Might be useful to see more of the exception in the question

Comment: added the complete stack trace.

Comment: Updated my answer, you need the Spring AOP dependency as well.

Comment: As a general rule, the end of the stack trace normally identifies the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You may also require additional dependencies even after including this, just see what the stack trace tells you once youve included the Spring AOP one (It should at least change error)

Comment: Well it AOP jar is comming from dependency hierarchy that is generated as part of maven for spring-data-jpa . Thus I have the AOP in my class path. Still the problem is not solved.

Comment: The error is suggesting its not on the class path. Check the aop dependency that has been included contains this class: `org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor` also check the scope of the dependency include

Comment: Problem solved, the reason was spring jpa xsd import and spring version difference.

Comment: Well done, maybe add an answer as it could help people in future

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the schema version of spring-data-jpa.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd>
```

Also you can checkout a video tutorial I created about how to configure Spring-Data: http://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/post/3